# Laravel Homestead Git Push

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Laravel 4.2 with Homestead.
Is it correct to push my local changes from Vagrant (homestead env.)?

My computer haven't any changes under project root (only on Homestead).

Comment: Voting to close as this is primarily opinion-based. But if you do push from inside the Homestead VM, be sure to set your Git user name and email configuration settings.

Comment: I think a got some bug with VM yesterday. I tried to call 'git status' and got 'warning: unable to access '/home/vagrant/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/home/vagrant/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied' inside the Homestead. And on my local machine everything ok.